# Columns showing up as rows

Tags: tabulator

I'm running Tabulator in an Angular project, and that Angular project is hosted as part of a SpringBoot Java application (in case that's adding a limitation.) All of the information is showing up in what would be the first column, and each column is showing up as a separate row (basically turning the entire table into a 1 column list.) Does anyone know why that might be? The code was copied from another project and shows up correctly there. What I'm thinking is that it's interpreting each line of the "columns:" block as separate lines of code, making them rows instead of columns.

Comment: I suppose that I should clarify, the Angular code shows up correctly on another system, it's not as part of a SpringBoot project, but I would think that the Angular app would be contained within itself rather than affected by what's hosting it.

Comment: My first thought is there is some CSS that is missing on the new system. Or possibly some extra, unrelated CSS is inadvertently getting applied to the table.

Comment: Other than that, we can only guess without seeing your actual code or site.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response (long weekend off) I think I found part of the problem, I had a project written that I copied from, but it appears that Tabulator has been updated quite a bit since then, so I have to rewrite the project. Thank you for the response!!